# _vm.arr[0] is undefined Vue.js, Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I've got a website. There's a main page with a navbar. Navbar contains of 2 links. There's a link (main-link) as well and it goes on other page. When I click on the main-link it opens a new page with the same navbar. I should click on any link and it will redirect me on them.

The issue:
If I click on the navbar on the main page and click on the main-link it works well. If go on the page by click the main-link I can use navbar. But if I refresh the page it doesnt work.
Here is the error from console:

```
_vm.arr[0] is undefined
```

components specialty.vue html section:

```html
<h2 v-if="$t(arr[0].link.name) == 'category-spec'">...</h2>
<h2 v-else-if="$t(arr[0].link.name) == 'customers-spec'">...</h2>
```

components specialty.vue script section:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    arr: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
      default: () => []
    }
  },
  components: {
    ...
  },
  setup () {
    return {
      ...
    }
  }
})
```

I guess that it broke because when I refresh the page the data about `arr` isn't recieved yet. But why other data is OK?

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3 templates, you could use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) on `arr[0]` so that `arr[0]` is only dereferenced when truthy:

```html
<h2 v-if="$t(arr[0]?.link.name) == 'category-spec'">...</h2>
                      
<h2 v-else-if="$t(arr[0]?.link.name) == 'customers-spec'">...</h2>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-optional-operator-in-vue-3-templates-viqyv?file=/src/components/MyComponent.vue:23-107)

Or you could check `arr[0]` beforehand:

```html
<h2 v-if="arr[0] && $t(arr[0].link.name) == 'category-spec'">...</h2>
<h2 v-else-if="arr[0] && $t(arr[0].link.name) == 'customers-spec'">...</h2>
```